# How to make uniform electrical contacts of AWG 2 inside chair lugs

Tags: electrical

[image: 2]

In the above picture, I inserted the AWG 2 in the chair lugs. You can see only the 3 of the 7 strands make contact with the bottom while only 1 strand make contact with the screw above. The 3 in middle have no contacts. So is there a rule how many strands must be in contacts? If the contacts are not sufficient, Could it cause arcing, heat, melting, etc.

Original message:

If the small chair lug on the left (of picture below) allows maximum size of AWG 2 wire, what if you use the AWG 2 wire on the larger lug?
Is it a requirement that the wire inside must touch all the surrounding circular surface?
I imagine if you use it on the large chair lugs, then the sides may not make contact and that this is not recommended?
What is the rule for ensuring full electrical contacts inside the lugs to avoid arcing, etc.?

[image: 1]

Comment: If you measure the hole in the chair I will see if I have one that matches the size. I have to use listed parts and they all have the wire sizes stamped on them.

Comment: Samzun, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if you're not clear on how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

Lugs typically have a range of acceptable sizes.  The wire just needs to be big enough to actually get caught under the set screw and be reasonably centered when it is torqued. The documentation will say, and often it is inscribed onto the part.  E.g. `2/0-6` meaning 2/0 is the largest that will fir and 6 is the smallest that will behave properly.

Comment: Please see edited pics above. If only 4 of the 7 strands make contacts with the lugs.. is the area sufficient to prevent arcing, heat, melting, etc.? Please show any rule of how many minimum contacts must there be, thanks.

Comment: There isn't such a rule, except for quality-of-workmanship rules, i.e. Don't let strands splay all out.  Note how not all the strands touch the aluminum, but each one touches a strand which touches the aluminum or setscrew. It is a fairly long lug with a lot of contact area longitudinally.  This is fine, ulnless an infrared thermometer tells otherwise.

Comment: Btw.. for something related, an electrical engineer taught me how to compute if the bus bar stab and spring clips make sufficient contacts. He said: Compute the area as you would any rectangle. Remember that there is still a gap for a short distance below the edge of the feeler gauge.
I've never investigated that. But it would seem the contact area would have to be no less than the cross sectional area of the maximum wire size for the breaker... and probably a little more because of the added resistance due to the pressure contact versus the continuous metal of a wire." Hav you computed 1 b4?

Comment: or go to this thread about zoomed in picture of the gaps and how to compute for the area.. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150896/how-to-compute-panel-bus-bar-stab-and-breaker-spring-clip-electrical-contacts-ar

Comment: Harper, kindly go see my first Answer as I tried to compute the area... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150896/how-to-compute-panel-bus-bar-stab-and-breaker-spring-clip-electrical-contacts-ar/151100#151100  Please let me know what is wrong if there is any in the computations. This will be my last inquiry. After that. I will no longer post in stack exchange for a long time. It's not my thing to post here. So Ed and others, please bear with me for this last important inquiry that can answer whether Siemens need to recall thousands of the GFCI 2-pole which they also did in 1998.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required that the wire entering the barrel of the lug touch all of the interior of the barrel.  Actually that is of no concern regarding the size rating of the lug. The size rating of the lug just indicates the size parameters of the wire safely using this lug. The wire too small and it could get lost in the hole; too large and it will not fit the opening.  Once the proper sized wire is in the hole, just cinched the screw down tight.

Comment: But is it not if the contacts are few. It can cause arcing, resistive heating, melting and fire?

Comment: What causes those things is loose connections.

Comment: You mean if the contacts are not enough. It can just cause heating and not arcing?